# On Ramanujan's Question 359

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, radicals, conjectures

In JIMS 4, p.78, Question 359 was asked by Ramanujan. (See *[The Problems Submitted by Ramanujan to the Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.9228&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*, p. 9, by Bruce Berndt, et al.) If,

$$\sin(x+y) = 2\sin\big(\tfrac{1}{2}(x-y)\big)\tag1$$

$$\sin(y+z) = 2\sin\big(\tfrac{1}{2}(y-z)\big)\tag2$$

prove that,

$$\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\sin x\cos z\big)^{1/4}+\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x\sin z\big)^{1/4} =\big(\sin 2y)^{1/12}\tag3$$

The example by Ramanujan was,

$$\begin{aligned}
x &= \frac{\pi-\arcsin\big((\sqrt{5}-2)^3(4+\sqrt{15})^2\big)}{2}=1.094\dots\\ 
y &=\frac{\arcsin\big(\sqrt{5}-2\big)}{2}=0.119\dots\\
z &=\frac{\arcsin\big((\sqrt{5}-2)^3(4-\sqrt{15})^2\big)}{2}=0.0001\dots
\end{aligned}$$

Ten years later, a 3-page proof was given in JIMS 15, p.114-117.

---

I got an email asking if there was a shorter proof. Considering the problem, I observed the following. Given the quartic,

$$a^3w^4+(1-3a^2)w^3+3a(1-a^2)w^2+a^2(3-a^2)w-a=0\tag4$$
with $a=\tan(\color{blue}y/4)$. Define,
$$x=4\tan^{-1} u\\z=4\tan^{-1} v$$ 
where $u,v$ are *two* appropriate roots of the quartic, then we get the ***same*** bizarre relation as Ramanujan,

$$\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\sin x\cos z\big)^{1/4}+\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x\sin z\big)^{1/4} =\big(\sin 2\color{blue}y)^{1/12}\tag5$$

Equivalently, those two roots $u,v$ obey,

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{4(u-u^3)}{(u^2+1)^2}\frac{v^4-6v^2+1}{(v^2+1)^2} \right)^{1/4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{4(v-v^3)}{(v^2+1)^2}\frac{u^4-6u^2+1}{(u^2+1)^2} \right)^{1/4}=\big(\sin 2\color{blue}y\big)^{1/12}\tag6$$

For example, let $y=1$, so $a=\tan(1/4)$, then $u,v$ are the two real roots of (4).

***Question***: Anyone knows a short proof for (3) and (6)?

Comment: I can't read the post, part of it is cut off. Is this something everyone's facing?

Comment: If Ramanujan couldn't solve it...

Comment: @nbubis can you imagine if Ramanujan had lived long enough to be on math.se?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber - Just saying :) maybe it should be on MO since it seems to involve research level mathematics.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee, yes: I've the same problem. The post is cut off.

Comment: If you use Google Chrome then the post is fine, but if you an old version of MS Explorer then it is cut-off. Don't know why.

Comment: Let's say I am considering proving (3)........What I could see is that $x=75  degrees$, $y=15  degrees$ and $z=435  degrees$ satisfy equations (1) and (2)...But they don't satisfy (3)....Can anybody please check and see if there is actually something wrong with (3) or not?

Comment: @AkashBajaj: I've edited the post to add a link to Berndt's paper and the page where the proposed relation is given. Hm, you're right, I can't get your example to work nor Ramanujan's in the cited paper. It's been a long time, maybe I forgot to use an assumption.

Comment: Thanks @TitoPiezasIII ....also, it would be great if you could post a link to that 3-page proof you mentioned above....if you have it.....that would help us check how they verified the solutions...

Comment: It's ok....I got that now...the angles must be acute

Comment: @AkashBajaj: I edited again to add Ramanujan's example. I find the angles of his $x,y,z$ (multiplied by $180/\pi$) as approximately $64.6,\, 6.8,\, 0.006$ so they are all acute. May I know the reference regarding how $x,y,z$ should have acute angles?

Comment: Yeah...I got the same ones...I don't have a reference....I guessed that would be the assumption since my values didn't work out.....I am "hoping" that the angles must be acute... :\

Comment: @AkashBajaj: Ah, I see :\ But it's good as your example can be used to refine the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to a deleted answer by G. Manco, we finally have a partial answer *after four years* to a closed-form solution $x,y,z$ to,
$$\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\sin x\cos z\big)^{1/4}+\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x\sin z\big)^{1/4} =\big(\sin 2y)^{1/12}\tag3$$
in terms of the *Ramanujan G function.* Using the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$, this can be calculated in Mathematica as,
$$G_n=\frac{2^{-1/4}\,\eta^2(\sqrt{-n})}{\eta\big(\tfrac{\sqrt{-n}}{2}\big)\,\eta(2\sqrt{-n})}\tag4$$
However, because of the constraints $(1),(2)$ in the post, there is a difference when $1\leq n\leq9$ and $n\geq9$. Thus,

If $1\leq n\leq9$:
$$\begin{aligned}
x &=\pi/2-\tfrac12\arcsin G_{n/9}^{-12}\\
y &=\tfrac12\arcsin G_{n}^{-12}\\
z &=\tfrac12\arcsin G_{9n}^{-12}
\end{aligned}$$
If $n\geq9$:
$$\begin{aligned}
x &=\tfrac12\arcsin G_{n/9}^{-12}\\
y &=\tfrac12\arcsin G_{n}^{-12}\\
z &=\tfrac12\arcsin G_{9n}^{-12}
\end{aligned}$$
We recover Ramanujan's solution $x,y,z \approx 1.094,\; 0.119,\; 0.0001$ by plugging in $n=5$ to the first set of formulas.  Also, since,

$$\sin(\tfrac12\arcsin \lambda)=\tfrac12\big(\sqrt{1+\lambda}-\sqrt{1-\lambda}\big)$$
$$\cos(\tfrac12\arcsin \lambda)=\tfrac12\big(\sqrt{1+\lambda}+\sqrt{1-\lambda}\big)$$
then $(3)$ can be expressed in radical form,

$$\left(\tfrac12\Big(\tfrac{\sqrt{1+\alpha}+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}2\Big)\Big(\tfrac{\sqrt{1+\beta}\,\color{blue}\pm\,\sqrt{1-\beta}}2\Big)\right)^{1/4}+\left(\tfrac12\Big(\tfrac{\sqrt{1+\alpha}-\sqrt{1-\alpha}}2\Big)\Big(\tfrac{\sqrt{1+\beta}\,\color{blue}\mp\,\sqrt{1-\beta}}2\Big)\right)^{1/4}=\gamma^{1/12}$$
where $\alpha = G_{n/9}^{-12},\;\beta= G_{9n}^{-12},\;\gamma= G_{n}^{-12}$ and the $+,-$ case for $n\leq9$ and $-,+$ case for $n\geq9$.

**P.S.** The second part of the question is still a bit tricky to prove.

Comment: Wow! You do amazing stuff. I am in awe.

Comment: @martycohen: Ah, thanks. :)

Answer (score 10):

**An elegant solution to question 359 submitted by Ramanujan to Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society.**

The three equations (1)-(3) are three modular equations: the first two are of third degree and the last one of ninth degree. These equations are in Ramanujan's notebooks: http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/index.html.

If $\alpha$ be of the $1^{st}$, $\beta$ the $3^{rd}$ and $\gamma$ the $9^{th}$ degree then.

$\sqrt{\alpha(1-\beta)}$+$\sqrt{\beta(1-\alpha)}$=$2(\alpha\beta(1-\alpha)(1-\beta))^\frac {1} {8}$$\tag1$

$\sqrt{\gamma(1-\beta)}$+$\sqrt{\beta(1-\gamma)}$=$2(\beta \gamma (1-\beta)(1-\gamma))^\frac{1} {8}$$\tag2$

and

$(\alpha(1-\gamma))^\frac{1}{8}$+
$(\gamma(1-\alpha))^\frac{1}{8}$=$2^\frac{1}{ 3}$($\beta(1-\beta))^\frac{1}{24}$ $\tag3$

Here is my interpretation. The reading key is:

$\sqrt{\alpha}=\sin{x}$,  $\sqrt{\beta}=\sin{y}$, and $\sqrt{\gamma}=\sin{z}$

moreover

$\sqrt{1-\alpha}=\cos x$, $\sqrt{1-\beta}=\cos y$ and $\sqrt{1-\gamma}=\cos z$.

and with class invariants

$4\alpha(1-\alpha)G_{\frac n 9}^{24}=1$, $4\beta(1-\beta)G_{n}^{24}=1$, and  $4\gamma(1-\gamma)G_{9n}^{24}=1$

or

$\sin{2x}.G_{\frac {n} {9}}^{12}=1$ ,  $\sin{2y}.G_{n}^{12}=1$ , and   $\sin{2z}.G_{9n}^{12}=1$.

For $n=5$ we have

$\sin 2x=2\sqrt{\alpha(1-\alpha)}
=G_{\frac {5} {9}}^{-12}$=$((\sqrt 5+2)^{\frac 1 4}(4-\sqrt{15})^{\frac 1 6})^{-12}=(\sqrt 5-2)^3(4+\sqrt 15)^2$

$\sin 2y=2\sqrt{\beta(1-\beta)}=G_{5}^{-12}=\big((\frac {\sqrt 5+1}{2})^{\frac1 4}\big)^{-12}=(\sqrt 5-2)$

$\sin 2z=2\sqrt{\gamma(1-\gamma)}=G_{45}^{-12}=((\sqrt 5+2)^{\frac 1 4}(4+\sqrt{15})^{\frac 1 6})^{-12}=(\sqrt 5-2)^3(4-\sqrt 15)^2$

$(\frac 1 2 \sin x \cos z)^{\frac 1 4}=\frac{ 1} {\sqrt 2}(\sqrt 5-2)^{\frac 3 4}\big(\sqrt \frac {7+3\sqrt 5}{4}+\sqrt \frac {3+3\sqrt 5}{4}\big)$

$(\frac 1 2 \sin z \cos x)^{\frac 1 4}=\frac{ 1} {\sqrt 2}(\sqrt 5-2)^{\frac 3 4}\big(\sqrt \frac {7+3\sqrt 5}{4}-\sqrt \frac {3+3\sqrt 5}{4}\big)$

adding we have

$\frac{ 1} {\sqrt 2}(\sqrt 5-2)^{\frac 3 4}\big(2\sqrt \frac {7+3\sqrt 5}{4}\big)=(\sqrt 5-2)^{\frac 1 {12}}=(\frac {\sqrt 5-1}{2})^{\frac1 4}$

This result is also equal to

$(\sin 2y )^{\frac {1} {12}}=\frac {1} {G_{5}}=(\frac {\sqrt 5-1}{2})^{\frac{1} {4}}$

I calculated several solutions for $n=1,1/2,2,3,1/3,4,1/4,5,1/5,6,1/6,7,1/7,8,1/8,9,1/9,10,1/10,15,1/15.$

For $n=12$ 
we have

$\sin x$=$(\sqrt{2}+1)^2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^2$

$\sin y$=$(\sqrt{2}-1)^2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^2$

$\sin z$=$\frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\delta}}} {2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\delta}}}$

with

$\delta=3-100.2^{\frac{1} {3}}+80.2^{\frac{2} {3}}$.

Comment: +1 Can you do a similar detailed analysis on your two answers for [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625/)? It will be appreciated by the forum.

Comment: (+1) Can you link the reference to the solution by Ramanujan. I searched but the solutions I found were from other mathematicians 10 years later.

Comment: Ramanujan never published solutions, I think.