# How prove $\root 4\of{\frac{1}{2}\sin x\cos z}+\root 4\of{\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin z}=\root{12}\of{\sin 2y} $?

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\sin(x+y) = 2\sin\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)$ and $\sin(y+z) = 2\sin\left(\dfrac{y-z}{2}\right)$.

How prove  $\root 4\of{\frac{1}{2}\sin x\cos z}+\root 4\of{\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin z}=\root{12}\of{\sin 2y} $  ?

Comment: This is Ramanujan's question 359. See this [similar post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310026/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Ramanujan's Question 359](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310026/on-ramanujans-question-359)