# Trigonometric system of 3 equations with many solutions in radical form.

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

Here is another (Ramanujan's type) trigonometric system of three equations.

Question:
"
If

$(\sin{x}\sin{y})^{1/4}+(\cos{x} \cos{y})^{1/4}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}(\sin{2x} \sin {2y})^{1/4}} \tag1$

$(\sin{y}\sin{z})^{1/4}+(\cos{y} \cos{z})^{1/4}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}(\sin{2y} \sin {2z})^{1/4}} \tag2$

then

$(\sin{x} \cos{z})^{1/4}+(\cos{x} \sin{z})^{1/4}=(8\sin{2y})^{1/12}\tag3$

One solution is:

$\sin{2y}=\sqrt{5}-2;$

$\sin{2x}=(\sqrt{5}-2)^3 (4+\sqrt{15})^2;$

$\sin{2z}=(\sqrt{5}-2)^3 (4-\sqrt{15})^2.$

To respond to Somos, I start with the values of $n=1,\cfrac{1}{2}, 2$.

For $n=1$ we have:

$\sin x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+2 \cdot 12^{1/4}-108^{1/4}}$

$\sin y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$\sin z=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-2 \cdot 12^{1/4}+108^{1/4}}$.

For $n=\frac{1}{2}$ we have:

$\sin x=\sqrt{2} \cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)^{3/2} \cdot (2-\sqrt{3})\cdot(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^{2}$

$\sin y=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}$

$\sin z=\sqrt{2}\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)^{3/2}\cdot (2+\sqrt{3})\cdot(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^{2}$.

For $n=2$ we have:

$\sin x= (\sqrt{2}-1)^{3}\cdot (2-\sqrt{3})^{2}$

$\sin y=(\sqrt{2}-1)$

$\sin z=(\sqrt{2}-1)^{3}\cdot (2+\sqrt{3})^{2}$.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: To find almost another solution.

Comment: An answer to [MSE question 310026](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/310026) 
"On Ramanujan's Question 359" by proposer is very related.

Comment: The last sentence of your [answer to MSE question 310026](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2102968/438089) is "I calculated several solutions for $n=1,1/2,2,3,1/3,4,1/4,5,1/5,6,1/6,7,1/7,8,1/8,9,1/9,10,1/10,15,1/15$." Why don't you tell us more about these solutions?

Comment: From equation $(3)$ it appears that $\sin x, \sin y, \sin z$ are elliptic moduli of first third and ninth degree. But equations $(1),(2)$ don't seem to be related to third degree modular equation. Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: The first equation should be $() ^{1/4}+()^{1/4}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}()^{1/4}}$ and similar for second equation.

Comment: It is ok. The 2 is 2^(1/2). Thank you.